# Terraform init throws plugin installation error

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Folks, I am trying to run a basic terraform code in my windows 10, Initially i thought this is an issue with the path or something and then I switched to CMD from VSCode (gitbash terminal), but still I am unable to get thru this, please help me with this error

My Terraform code:
main.tf

```
terraform {
  required_version = "0.15.0"
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~> 2.0"
    }
    azuread = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azuread"
      version = "~> 1.0"
    }
    random = {
      source  = "hashicorp/random"
      version = "~> 3.0"
    }
  }

    backend "azurerm" {
    resource_group_name   = "terraform-strg-rg"
    storage_account_name  = "terraformstatexxxxxx"
    container_name        = "tfstatefiles"
    key                   = "terraform.tfstate"
  }  
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {

  }
}

resource "random_pet" "aksrandom" {

}
```

Terraform Version that i am using on windows 10:

```
$ terraform -v
Terraform v0.15.0
on windows_amd64
```

Terraform init command:

```
$ terraform init

Initializing the backend...

Initializing provider plugins...
- Finding hashicorp/random versions matching "~> 3.0"...
- Finding hashicorp/azurerm versions matching "~> 2.0"...
- Finding hashicorp/azuread versions matching "~> 1.0"...
- Installing hashicorp/azurerm v2.99.0...
- Installing hashicorp/azuread v1.6.0...
- Installing hashicorp/random v3.4.3...
╷
│ Error: Failed to install provider
│
│ Error while installing hashicorp/azurerm v2.99.0: open
│ .terraform\providers\registry.terraform.io\hashicorp\azurerm\2.99.0\windows_amd64\terraform-provider-azurerm_v2.99.0_x5.exe:
│ The system cannot find the path specified.
╵

╷
│ Error: Failed to install provider
│
│ Error while installing hashicorp/azuread v1.6.0: open
│ .terraform\providers\registry.terraform.io\hashicorp\azuread\1.6.0\windows_amd64\terraform-provider-azuread_v1.6.0_x5.exe:
│ The system cannot find the path specified.
╵

╷
│ Error: Failed to install provider
│
│ Error while installing hashicorp/random v3.4.3: open
│ .terraform\providers\registry.terraform.io\hashicorp\random\3.4.3\windows_amd64\terraform-provider-random_v3.4.3_x5.exe:
│ The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the follwing providers in ***`providers.tf`*** file:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
  
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
       version = "=3.40.0"
    }    
        
    azuread = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azuread"
      version = "= 2.28.1"
    }


    random = {
      source  = "hashicorp/random"
      version = "=3.1.2"
    }

     azapi = {
      source = "Azure/azapi"
    }

  }
}
```

[image]

These providers are initialized successfully:

[image]

Check the version of terraform with

```
terraform -v
```

I have the following version:

```
Terraform v1.0.7
on windows_amd64
```

You have given **required_version = "0.15.0"**  which looks like not supported or compatible.

Make sure you have compatible versions of terraform .
If the versions fail

[image]

The issue can be resolved by upgrading terraform modules using

***`Terraform init -upgrade`***

When you run the command: **terraform providers lock**, it must have ID something like  below:

```
Fetching azure/azapi 1.4.0 for windows_amd64...
- Obtained azure/azapi checksums for windows_amd64 (signed by a HashiCorp partner, key ID 6F0B9xxxxF)
```

Make sure the terraform registry files are in root module:

[image]

[image]

And run the VSCode **as administrator**

Try to delete `.terraform` directory and run `terraform init` again

Reference : [/terraform_init_throws_plugin_installation_error | reddit.com](https://www.reddit.com/r/Terraform/comments/11tgozh/terraform_init_throws_plugin_installation_error/)